# GWT 2.5.0 compiler exception

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction

Our team tries to upgrade from GWT 2.4.0 to 2.5.0, but now we are facing the problem - the compiler throws an exception. Here is the compiler log:

> binding: user.agent=safari binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
>   binding: locale=en Compiling module app.m8.web.AGM    Validating
>   units:
>         Ignored 3 units with compilation errors in first pass. Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all
>   errors.    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error
>   during visit.     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:109)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:116)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JReturnStatement.traverse(JReturnStatement.java:39)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:83)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:82)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:426)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:395)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:902)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:627)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:624)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:89)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.(ModuleState.java:54)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:88)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod cannot be cast to
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JConstructor   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JNewInstance.getTarget(JNewInstance.java:56)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:275)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JNewInstance.traverse(JNewInstance.java:86)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
>     ... 31 more
>         [ERROR] at Contact_FieldSerializer.java(65): 
>            com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JNewInstance
>         [ERROR] at Contact_FieldSerializer.java(65): 
>            com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JReturnStatement
>         [ERROR] at Contact_FieldSerializer.java(64): 
>            com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
>         [ERROR] at Contact_FieldSerializer.java(64): 
>            com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
>         [ERROR] at Contact_FieldSerializer.java(64): public static Contact instantiate(SerializationStreamReader streamReader);
>            com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod [ERROR] Compiler returned false

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JNewInstance#getTarget` to see what method the `JMethod` represents? Also check your `Contact_FieldSerializer#instantiate` code.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Thomas. The reason was found and now everything works fine. This method wasn't actually a method. We have a class Contact implements Serializable. It must contain default constructor, but instead it has public void Contact() {}. That was the reason. The issue is closed.

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue (with some code to reproduce if possible): https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7824

Answer (score 8):

delete files in **

> gwt-unitCache

**  which is present in your project folder