# Error constructing Java AST Exception while launching Devmode

Tags: gwt

Getting the below exception While Launching DevMode,I read some of the link which has same issue [GWT 2.5.0 compiler exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641849/gwt-2-5-0-compiler-exception)
 but not able to solve and using GWT 2.6.1

```
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Error constructing Java AST
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.translateException(GwtAstBuilder.java:3172)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CastExpression.traverse(CastExpression.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.traverse(Assignment.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.traverse(IfStatement.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.traverse(MessageSend.java:663)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1327)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3131)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:127)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:880)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:284)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:511)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:434)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:420)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:495)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:104)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BaseTypeBinding
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.unbox(GwtAstBuilder.java:2809)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.maybeBoxOrUnbox(GwtAstBuilder.java:2414)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.simplify(GwtAstBuilder.java:2803)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.pop(GwtAstBuilder.java:1959)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CastExpression.traverse(CastExpression.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.traverse(Assignment.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.traverse(IfStatement.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedAllocationExpression.traverse(QualifiedAllocationExpression.java:552)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.traverse(MessageSend.java:663)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:307)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1327)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3131)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:127)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:880)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:284)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:511)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:434)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:420)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:495)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:104)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's fixed in 2.7

See https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8714